# Why isn't this code triggering paint()?

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint

It runs, the buttons work, but i just can't get it to draw with the paint(). I think it has something to do with the main method on SwingDraw, but i'm not 100% sure. Thanks for any help and sorry for the long code :/

SwingDraw:

```
// Import Core Java packages
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingDraw extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener{

// Initial Frame size
static final int WIDTH = 1500;                // frame width
static final int HEIGHT = 1000;               // frame height

// Color choices
static final String[] COLOR_NAMES = new String[]{"None", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
static final Color COLORS[] = {null, Color.red, Color.blue, Color.green }; 

// Button control
JButton circle;
JButton roundRec;
JButton threeDRec;
JButton line;
JButton square;
JButton oval;

JButton clear;
JButton delete;

// List to keep track of shapes
JList<String> shapesKeeper;

// Color choice box
JComboBox<String> colorChoice = new JComboBox<>(COLOR_NAMES);

SwingDrawCanvas betterCanvas = new SwingDrawCanvas();

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public SwingDraw() {
    // Create a frame
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setLocation(130, 100);
    // add window closing listener
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    // create panel for controls
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel leftList = new JPanel();



    // create button control 
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); 
    topPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    circle = new JButton("Circle");
    buttonPanel.add(circle);
    roundRec = new JButton("Rounded Rectangle");
    buttonPanel.add(roundRec);
    threeDRec = new JButton("3D Rectangle");
    buttonPanel.add(threeDRec);
    line = new JButton("Line");
    buttonPanel.add(line);
    square = new JButton("Square");
    buttonPanel.add(square);
    oval = new JButton("Oval");
    buttonPanel.add(oval);
    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    buttonPanel.add(clear);

    JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
    leftList.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    JList<String> shapesKeeper = new JList<>();
    listPanel.add(shapesKeeper);
    delete = new JButton("Delete Shape");
    listPanel.add(delete);

    // add button listener
    circle.addActionListener(this);
    roundRec.addActionListener(this);
    threeDRec.addActionListener(this);
    line.addActionListener(this);
    square.addActionListener(this);
    oval.addActionListener(this);
    clear.addActionListener(this);

    // create panel for color choices
    JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Filled Color:");
    topPanel.add(colorPanel);
    colorPanel.add(label);
    JComboBox<String> colorChoice = new JComboBox<>(COLOR_NAMES);
    colorPanel.add(colorChoice);

    colorChoice.addItemListener(this);

    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(leftList, BorderLayout.WEST);
    setVisible(true);

} // end of constructor


/**
 *  Implementing ActionListener
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource() == circle) {  // circle button
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.CIRCLE);
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == roundRec) {  // rounded rectangle button
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.ROUNDED_RECTANGLE);
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == threeDRec) { // 3D rectangle button
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.RECTANGLE_3D);
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == clear){
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.CLEAR);
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == line){
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.LINE);
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == square){
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.SQUARE);
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == oval){
        betterCanvas.setShape(SwingDrawCanvas.OVAL);

    }
}

/**
 * Implementing ItemListener
 */
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    Color color = COLORS[colorChoice.getSelectedIndex()];
    betterCanvas.setFilledColor(color);
}

/**
 * the main method
 */
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    new SwingDraw();
}
}
```

SwingDrawCanvas:

```
public class SwingDrawCanvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

// Constants for shapes
public static final int CIRCLE = 1;
public static final int ROUNDED_RECTANGLE = 2;
public static final int RECTANGLE_3D = 3;
public static final int LINE = 4;
public static final int SQUARE = 5;
public static final int OVAL = 6;

public static final int CLEAR = 7;

// Coordinates of points to draw
private int x1, y1, x2, y2;

// shape to draw
private int shape = CIRCLE;
/**
 * Method to set the shape
 */
public void setShape(int thisShape) {
    System.out.println("HEY");
    this.shape = thisShape;
    System.out.println(shape);
}

// filled color
private Color filledColor = null;
/**
 * Method to set filled color
 */
public void setFilledColor(Color color) {
    filledColor = color;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public SwingDrawCanvas() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
} // end of constructor

/**
 * painting the component
 */
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    System.out.println("ARHFHASJDASHDHAs");
    super.paint(g);

    System.out.println("AHAHAHAHAHAHAHA");

    g.drawString("FUCK", 1, 1);

    // the drawing area
    int x, y, width, height;

    // determine the upper-left corner of bounding rectangle
    x = Math.min(x1, x2);
    y = Math.min(y1, y2);

    // determine the width and height of bounding rectangle
    width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
    height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);


    if(filledColor != null)
        g.setColor(filledColor);
    switch (shape) {
        case ROUNDED_RECTANGLE :
            if(filledColor == null)
                g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, width/4, height/4);
            else
                g.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, width/4, height/4);
            break;
        case CIRCLE :
            int diameter = Math.max(width, height); 
            if(filledColor == null)
                System.out.println("HRE BITCHS");
            else
                System.out.println("HEY FUCK YOU GUY");
            break;
        case RECTANGLE_3D :
            if(filledColor == null)
                g.draw3DRect(x, y, width, height, true);
            else
                g.fill3DRect(x, y, width, height, true);
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Implementing MouseListener
 */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    x1 = event.getX();
    y1 = event.getY();
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    x2 = event.getX();
    y2 = event.getY();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

/**
 * Implementing MouseMotionListener
 */
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    x2 = event.getX();
    y2 = event.getY();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
```

}

I'm not very good at this, I'm just looking for any help you guys can give me :D

Comment: You need to add `betterCanvas` to your frame in `SwingDraw()`.

Comment: Your `SwingDrawCanvas` panel is never added to the frame .

Comment: In addition to those tips, change `public void paint(Graphics g) {` to `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` 1) The `@Override` method checks at compile time that the method exists. It is just good practice to use it whenever overriding any method. 2) The correct method in which to do custom painting for any `JComponent` or class that extends it it the `paintComponent(..)` method.

Comment: Wowza that was so simple it makes me wanna vomit. Thanks so much though! yall helped a million

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `paint()`, your function should be name `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. 
When creating the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` functions, you need `@Override` so that java recognizes the function because you can not call `paintComponent(Graphics g)` directly.

In addition, any time you want to refresh your panel, you can call `repaint()` or you can resize your JFrame after the code as compiled. Both of these methods will call the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function.